# dijit form select does not behave like HTML SELECT

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dijit.form.Select as a replacement for the HTML SELECT.
I am unable to get it to allow me to select an item purely by typing as you can with the HTML version. Ie, if you have a list of US states you can hit C several times to select Conneticut. What am I missing? TIA

And yet, it works on the web page below....
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test%5FSelect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A chap named Bob Tarling has solved my problem. Much obliged Bob!!
See this link for his solution http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Sharing-a-solution-for-type-ahead-in-Select-and-help-request-to-adapt-tt3995899.html#none

Answer (score 1):

When designing a `select` element that is visually consistent with a UI theme, CSS is often not powerful enough to completely control the look of `select` element, as some browsers treat CSS stylings on a select element differently. So the next best thing for many is to develop a faux-select with javascript so that way you have a better looking `select` element.

What you're left with is something that looks like a `select` element, but isn't, and the real select is hidden nearby, typically.

That means that there is a good possibility that when the developer was making that javascript version of the `select` element, they didn't do their diligence to at least program the minimum features that come native with the HTML version. (after all, it would be a lot of work to do string searching and sorting on a `keyup` event... and i'm not surprised they didn't do it)

to add insult to injury, sometimes the plugin actually allows for the change event on the native select to still be focused beneath the surface, which is why your typing works sometimes.